# "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." error when using TimerTask

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I have created an app composed of one single activity which include a single `TextView`. Here is the XML of my activity :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="zeratops.myApp.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:id="@+id/text_1"
            android:paddingTop="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code is to set the text of this `textView` every second. Here is the code I use to perform this task :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText("test");
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

**The issue**

I am facing the following issue when I launch load my app and launch it on my LG G2 :

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I identified the lines :

```
timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 1000);
```

causing the error since I do not have exceptions when I remove it. Am I mising some checking ?

Comment: In JDK you would wrap `text.setText("test");` with `Platform.runLater(){}`, android should have something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `run()` method will be called on a background thread, and it cannot manipulate the UI as a result.

A lighter-weight solution would be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);

        onEverySecond.run();
    }

    private Runnable onEverySecond=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText("test");
            text.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

`postDelayed()` calls your `run()` method on the main application thread, after the designated delay period. Here, we use that to have the `Runnable` schedule itself to run again after 1000ms.

To stop the `postDelayed()` "loop", call `removeCallbacks(onEverySecond)` on your `MainActivity`.

The advantage of this over using `runOnUiThread()` inside the `TimerTask` is that it is less expensive, as you are not creating a separate thread (the `Timer`/`TimerTask` thread).

Comment: Perfect. Just to mention, I had to put the `final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);` instanciation inside your `public void run() {` function in order to avoid scope errors. But without it, it saves the day pretty well !

Comment: @Zeratops: Or, make it a field -- I just updated my answer to show that. It saves you from making the `findViewById()` call unnecessarily every second.

Comment: I checked it works correctly. Thank your for your update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform

`text.setText("test");`

in UI thread. You can do so using Handlers.

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.post(myRunnable);



   final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        text.setText("test");
      }
   };
```